# How to display cobertura code coverage per class in devops correctly

Tags: code-coverage, devops, cobertura

I'm working on a pipeline in Azure Devops where we utilize unit-tests.

Because we're using OpenEdge (and the sonarqube license is rather pricy) I've written my own parser for the profiler file. It counts the (relevant) lines in our sourcecode and parses the lines ran during tests from the profiler file.
It calculates this number accordingly (so I think the issue might be in how I construct the cobertura.xml file).

Then I construct an Cobertura xml according to this structure:

```
<coverage timestamp version complexity branches-valid branches-covered lines-valid lines-covered branch-rate line-rate>
<packages>
<package complexity branch-rate line-rate name>
    <classes>
        <class complexity branch-rate line-rate name file-name>
            <methods>
                <method branch-rate line-rate name signature>
                    <lines>
                        <line branch hits number>
                        </line>
                    </lines>
                </method>
            </methods>
            <lines>
                <line branch hits number>
                </line>
            </lines>
        </class>
    </classes>
</package>
</packages>
</coverage>
```

Using this syntax the overall code coverage appears on the build summary tab.
Now I would like to see the coverage per class (or file in our case) (eventually also code coverage per procedure, which are now already filled in under ) on the "Code Coverage" tab inside the build.

Is it possible to do this in that way (I assume the "Publish Code Coverage" task in the pipeline should parse the Cobertura file and display its contents accordingly...)?

Or am I making some fundamental mistake here?

Thanks in advance,
Jacco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing the exact same thing over on GitHub here: [abl-profiler-converter](https://github.com/NickHeap2/abl-profiler-converter)

The way I'm getting the report is by feeding the Cobertura xml output into a report generator task such as this one: [ReportGenerator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator)